# Unwrap failed to solve 2 of 52 islands. edge seams may need to be added error

Tags: uv, error

Noobie here, I'm trying to unwrap this helm to put on a texture but Im running into this "failed to solve island" issue, I've tried adding seams but nothing changes. I've been at this for over 2 hours and I'm about to call it quits. Any help would be appreciated.[image: A zoom in on one of the selection causing a problem]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error message says:

> Unwrap failed to solve 2 of 52 island(s), edge seams may need to be
> added

And that is exactly the answer. You need to add seams. At the moment there are no seams at all on the model, just some edges marked as sharp. I assume you mistakenly marked them as sharp instead of as seams, could this be it?

What you could do in this case is go into edit mode and select one of the sharp edges that is supposed to be a seam, then Select Similar( <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>G</kbd> ) by sharpness and then mark them as seams( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>E</kbd>   ->   <kbd>M</kbd> ):

[image]